# React JS wait for function to execute before continue

Tags: reactjs, async-await, callback, settimeout

I've been trying to block execution until **handleConfirmAsyncProcess()** returns true and then stops loading. but loading keeps stopping before getting a response from **handleConfirmAsyncProcess()** (which keeps fetching for a value recursively from the backend).

Expected behavior: **dispatch(setLoading(false))** only exected when **handleConfirmAsyncProcess()** reach its termination condition (which is resp?.ConfirmFinished).

Real behavior: **dispatch(setLoading(false))** is executed while **handleConfirmAsyncProcess()** still fetching recursively.

loading
check the code below:

```
   const ConfirmFunc = useCallback(() => {

    // start loading
    dispatch(setLoading(true));

    return save(false)
      .then(({ success, errorMessage }) => 
        !success
          ? (async () => ({ success, errorMessage }))()
          : confirm()
      )
      .then(async ({ success, errorMessage }) => {
          var resp = await handleConfirmAsyncProcess()
          // execution should stop here until handleConfirmAsyncProcess return true
          .then(function () {
          console.log(resp);
          });
        return;
      })
      .finally(() => dispatch(setLoading(false))); // stop loading
  }, [param1, param2, param3]);



const handleConfirmAsyncProcess = async () => {
        setTimeout(async () => {

            const resp = await checkConfirmState(uniqueID);
            if (resp?.ConfirmFinished)
            {
                return resp?.ConfirmFinished;
            }
            else
            {
                await handleConfirmAsyncProcess();
            }
        }, 3000);
    };
```